# Converting TCHAR to string in C++

Tags: c++, tchar

I'm trying to convert a TCHAR to a string as in:

```
std::string mypath;
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName( NULL, path, MAX_PATH );
```

I need to set `mypath` to that of `path`. I did a simple loop and concatenated `path[index]` to `mypath` and this works but I don't like this way.

I'm new to C++ but have done plenty of C#. I've seen examples of the `GetModuleFileName` that passes in a "char" but it doesn't like it. It needs the `TCHAR` or a `LPWSTR`.

Answer (score 26):

TCHAR is a macro defined as a char or wchar depending on what you have your character set defined to. The default after 2008 is have the character set to unicode. this code works if you change your character set.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR* bob ="hi";
    string s = bob;    
}
```

Right click on the project settings and chage the folowing

[image]

if You want to use TCHAR as a Unicode character set use [wstring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3s3k55%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Better yet, define a typedef on `TCHAR`: `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;` and use `tstring` everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Setting the charactor set above worked. Now I can use type char in the GetModuleFileName method.

Comment: This gives me the error `a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "TCHAR *"`

Comment: @ThisClark Is TCHAR defined.  This works on VS2013 and 2015.  TCHAR is defined in tchar.h if that is not included this of course will not work.

Comment: You are the ONE the ONE and ONLY. Who really pin pointed the real pain of TCHAR. WOW it was great answer.

Answer (score 15):

When I **really** need to do it I use the following:

```
TCHAR  infoBuf[32767];
GetWindowsDirectory(infoBuf, 32767);
```

And then I convert it to a wstring which can be converted to a standard `std::string`:

```
wstring test(&infoBuf[0]); //convert to wstring
string test2(test.begin(), test.end()); //and convert to string.
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want the path in chars, you should call `GetModuleFilenameA`. That function takes `LPSTR` instead of `LPTSTR`.

Note that almost all Win32 functions that take or return strings have two version, one ending in `A` (ANSI?) and the other ending in `W` (wide).

Answer (score 5):

You can also convert from `_TCHAR*` to `char*` using `wcstombs` or `wcstombs_s` function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is a late answer but I have an idea.

```
{wstring test = User;
 std::wcout << test << std::endl;
 string test2(test.begin(), test.end());
 std::cout << test2 << std::endl;}
```

User is in this example the username as a `TCHAR`.
Now I can use the name as a `string` or `wstring`.
This is the easiest way to convert the `TCHAR` to a `string`.